# How do I hide/show submit button based on Parsley form validation in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, parsley.js

I am new to both parsley.js and meteor (1.0).  I am trying to figure out how to hide/show a form submit button based on whether the form fields have passed parsley validation.

My initial thought was to use a spacebars conditional in the HTML template to control the display of the button.  This would be driven by a template helper that would determine the validation status.  I attempted a helper like this:

```js
formValidates: function() {
    $('#myformid').parsley().subscribe('parsley:form:validated', function(parsleyForm) {
          if (true === parsleyForm.validationResult)
            return true
          else
            return false
        }
```

This generates an error telling me that parsley needs to be bound to an object (not sure what that means).

I should mention that parsley validation is otherwise working on the form (validates types, ranges, required, etc) and that I have a trigger on each form input of 'changed'.

This seems like it should be fairly straightforward but I am hampered by my lack of experience.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do. Typically, the form submit button is always present and, on form submit, you validate the form (using parsley). If this is not your case, can you explain how will you trigger the validation?

Comment: Perhaps I need to re-think my approach.  My thought was that I could use the change validation property on each parsley field to know whether the form was valid or not.  However, if they do not change anything on the form, obviously there wouldn't be a submit button and force them to use the back button.   I am still left with the question of not completely understanding what code is needed to determine if the form had been validated successfully.  THoughts on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the main advantages of Parsley is its UX/UI and here is how it works:

1. You create your DOM elements with the validations you need for each element
2. You bind `parsley()` to your form
3. You fill in your inputs

   Important note: When you fill the inputs for the first time (better yet, *until* the form is **validated** for the first time) there will be no errors, even if the fields are incorrect. What I mean to say is: The errors will be displayed after the first attempt to validate the form, no matter the javascript event you're using (`focusin`, `focusout`, `change`, ..).
4. You validate the form (automatically via form submit or manually)
5. The errors will be displayed. As of this moment, the errors will change based on your javascript event. That is, if you correct the field, the error will disappear.

So, in order to display the submit button based on the validation result, you'll need to have some other form to validate the form. You can validate the form via javascript with:

```js
// bind parsley to your form. This will create a ParsleyForm object
$("#myForm").parsley();

// manually validate the form. This will display the errors for each field
$("#myForm").parsley().validate();

// Check if the form is valid. Will return a boolean value
$("#myForm").parsley().isValid();
```

Tipically, I always display the submit button and have the following jQuery code to submit the form:

```js
// bind parlsey to the form
$( "#myForm" ).parsley(); 
// when the user clicks on the submit button or enters "Enter" in a field
$("#myForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
    // Validate form fields
    $(this).parsley().validate();
    // If the form is valid, will proceed with submission.
    if ($(this).parsley().isValid()) {
        console.log('valid');
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Notes:

- I haven't worked with meteor, so you might need to "convert" this information.
- If you're getting a warning in the console that looks like this:

  > You must bind Parsley on an existing element.

  This means that you're trying to bind parsley to a non-existing element. This will happen when you try `$("#someFormId").parsley()` and there isn't any element with the id `someFormId`.

Comment: THanks, this definitely nudged me in the right direction.  For completeness, this is what one needs to add to their .js file in meteor to initialize parsley: `Template.name.rendered = function () {

  // Setup parsley form validation
  // replace form with the id of your form
  $('#form').parsley({trigger: 'change'});
}`